# Call custom method from web api using angularjs $resource

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, ngresource

Here is my `Web Api` Action:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/CustomTemplate")]
public class CustomTemplateController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCustomTemplate")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomTemplate()
    {
         //Code 
    }
}
```

Here is my angularjs files:

**service file:**

```
'use strict';
app.factory('customService', ['$resource', 'ngAuthSettings', function ($resource, ngAuthSettings) {

var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;

return $resource(serviceBase + 'api/CustomTemplate/', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    getCustomTemplate: {
        url: 'GetCustomTemplate',
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false
    }
});
}]);
```

**my angularjs controller:**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('customController', [
    '$scope', 'customService', function ($scope, customService) 
    {
        customService.getCustomTemplate({},function (customTemplate) 
        {
            $scope.customTemplate = customTemplate;
        });        
    }
]);
```

My problem is, I am unable to call `GetCustomTemplate` from angularjs. Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call full URL

```
'use strict';
app.factory('customService', ['$resource', 'ngAuthSettings', function ($resource, ngAuthSettings) {

var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;

return $resource(serviceBase + 'api/CustomTemplate/', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    getCustomTemplate: {
        url: serviceBase +'api/CustomTemplate/GetCustomTemplate', //full URL + custom action
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false
    }
});
}]);
```

Comment: Stated working with serviceBase + 'api/CustomTemplate/'. Thanks :)